# What do you do with the Unicorn Horn?

Tags: candy-box-2

I found a unicorn horn in the Desert Castle.

Anyone can give me a hint as to what I'm supposed do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that it increases healing rate in general.

Comment: Ah Thank You. I thought i have to process it in any way but faster healing makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you healing, and yes, it stacks with pink gloves.